# Stuck on this Probability question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this revision question relating to probability. All it says is that I need to evaluate it:

$$
\sum_{r=1}^2 (-1)^{r-1} r!
$$

Can you help me answer it and show me how you did it.
Hope you can help thanks.

Comment: the sum is not very big so you can just calculate it by hand

Comment: What makes you think that you need "10 reputation" in order to post a question???

Comment: This is not going to go well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{r=1}^2 (-1)^{r-1} r!$ is the sum of **two** terms, each being *very* easy to compute. Don't let the $\sum$ symbol frighten you.

$$
(-1)^{1-1} 1! + (-1)^{2-1} 2! = \textbf{?}
$$

Comment: does it = -1? If not can you please show me what to do thanks

Comment: It does, yes. For this sort of verification/check, you should also learn how to use (or have the reflex to use) [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29%5E%28r-1%29*+r%21+for+r%3D1..2).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Well appreciated unlike the other comments people are sending me.